# Selecting between two options?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

On the options screen of my current application I want to allow the user to select whether units are displayed in either "Metric" or "Imperial". I have looked at the Google Maps application and they do this using a grouped UITableView, this does not really work for my application as I am presenting various configuration options from an "Options" tab on a ITabBar.

[image]

I have looked at segment control, which seems quite good, but on reading the Apple HIG I noticed that each segment when tapped is designed to display a different view.

[image]

I guess I could also go with a default and then use a UISwitch to toggle the alternate option.

[image]

My question is: What is the best way to do this in a none UITableView, is there a control that I am missing, any help / info would be much appreciated.

Comment: A segmented control doesn't have to display different views does it? I read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) which says it _can_ display views, but it also says 'Use a segmented control to offer closely related, but mutually exclusive choices.'

Comment: what about the picker views then?

Comment: There is a little more info on the version of the HIG that you list, so it does indeed look like it might be a good choice for what I am after, much appreciated.

Comment: @holex I will certainly look at UIPicker, although with only two options the UISegmentedControl might make more sense, but its good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be just fine using the segmented control, I've seen many applications that use it for selection, and I've used it in several applications as well where a tableView just didn't fit.

You could also look into a UIPicker, but segmented control has the advantage of setting an option in a lesser amount of taps, which is always a welcome usability trait.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the UISegmentedControl, it does look the best option both from a design and functionality stand point.